# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library

Tags: qt, standalone, py2exe, pyqt5

I run my exe on cmd by passing argument and get this error:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50902) with this library (version 0x50901)
```

How can I fix the problem?

It is an standalone application and I give the path on cmd window at the beginning like that (my exe file name is "path2Shape"):

```
path2Shape.py C:\Users\Mustafa Uçar\Desktop\Tutorial\Mississippi\mississippi.shp
```

Here is my code of the exe file:

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui

app = QgsApplication([], True)
path = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev"
app.setPrefixPath(path, True)
app.initQgis()

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
title = "PyQGIS Standalone Application Example"
canvas.setWindowTitle(title)
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

filepath = sys.argv[0]

layer = QgsVectorLayer(filepath, "testlayer", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
canvas.setLayers([layer])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()

canvas.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I added

`print (sys.argv[0])`

and then I wrote:

```
filepath = sys.argv[1]
```

when I am writing on cmd I used this:

```
python3 path2Shape.py C:\Mississippi\mississippi.shp
```

There is one more thing and maybe the most important:

My folder name in users has invalid character and gaps as you can see. So I changed the folder direction of the *.shp file and I moved it to C:\ to avoid "Mustafa Uçar".

Then it works!